# passing array into isin() function in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a requirement where I will have to filter records from a df if that is present in one array. so I have an array that is distinct values from another df's column like below.

```
dist_eventCodes = Event_code.select('Value').distinct().collect()
```

now I am passing this dist_eventCodes in a filter like below.

```
ADT_df_select = ADT_df.filter(ADT_df.eventTypeCode.isin(dist_eventCodes))
```

when I run this code I get the below error message

```
"AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'"
```

can somebody please help me under what wrong am i doing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to retain only those rows where `eventTypeCode` is within `eventTypeCode` from Event_code dataframe

Let me know if this is not the case

This can be achieved by a simple `left-semi` join in spark. This way you don't need to collect the dataframe, thus would be the right way in a distributed environment.

```
ADT_df.alias("df1").join(Event_code.select("value").distinct().alias("df2"), [F.col("df1.eventTypeCode")=F.col("df2.value")], 'leftsemi')
```

Or if there is a specific need to use `isin`, this would work (collect_set will take care of distinct):

```
dist_eventCodes = Event_code.select("value").groupBy(F.lit("dummy")).agg(F.collect_set("value").alias("value")).first().asDict()
ADT_df_select = ADT_df.filter(ADT_df["eventTypeCode"].isin(dist_eventCodes["value"]))
```

Input (ADT_df):

[image: ADT_df]

Event_code Dataframe:

[image: Event_code]

Output:

[image: Output]